# View isn't rotating properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, rotation

I have this code inside a `UIViewController` subclass:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {            
        self.view.frame = [PDToolbox screenFrame];
        self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The only thing I have in terms of any rotation methods is this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Yet after the screen is rotated to landscape, doing an NSLog on the view shows this:

```
<UIView: 0x10061640; frame = (0 0; 320 480); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10061670>>
```

I don't understand why it's doing this transform thing, and not just rotating like normal? It means any views i place on top of it after the rotation and set to be the size of the view end up at a 320x480 position.

EDIT:

People aren't understanding. So I put a view on top of it, the same size as the UIView, using:

```
UIView *anotherView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:controller.view.bounds];
[controller.view addSubview:anotherView];
```

If I add anotherView in in portrait, anotherView appears in portrait, with the frame 320x480.

If i add anotherView in in landscape, anotherView appears in landscape, but still with the frame 320x480, becaus that's what the controller.view's frame is still, for some unknown reason.

Comment: Could you just post a whole code of your UIViewCOntroller

Comment: @R.A Sure. Just done it.

Comment: Actually i dont understand your problem..What do you mean by this?"views i place on top of it after the rotation and set to be the size of the view end up at a 320x480 position"

Comment: Are you adding this view directly to the window or something? This is very odd behaviour that's typically managed (correctly) by your view controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

What does your view/controller hierarchy look like? It looks to me like something is setting a 90° rotation transformation on your view, rather than changing the view's frame. If you're not doing that yourself, it's likely a parent view or view controller.

Comment: It's a direct subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: I don't mean the class hierarchy of your UIViewController class, I mean view hierarchy of your application. Is the controller's view embedded in another view or is it placed directly in the application's UIWindow?

Comment: It's the normal view that comes with a UIViewController. That hasn't been modified.

Comment: Yes, but what's the view you're placing it in? Is it appearing inside a custom subclass of a UINavigationController or something?

Answer (score 0):

Frame and bounds are very different things. You should read Apple's guide to [View Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html) - it contains a lot of information that's been invaluable to me.

Your bounds is always going to be 320x480 because someone is setting your `transform` (which affects the `frame`, but not the `bounds`).

Make sure your view controller's view's superview has `autoresizesSubviews` set to `YES` and that any subviews added have appropriate `autoresizingMask`s.